# Locking a Linux serial port or other device in Mono

Tags: linux, mono, serial-port, locking

In Linux, applications normally lock serial ports for exclusive use by creating a corresponding lock file in `/var/lock/` with a name something like `LCK..ttyS1`.

- [Serial HOWTO: Locking Out Others](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-13.html)
- [`liblockdev`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockdev)
- [`liblockfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockfile_create) (thought it isn't as full-featured as `liblockdev`—it doesn't handle symlinks or multiple device files with the same device numbers)

Does Mono implement this locking of serial ports? I found [this bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693370) which suggests it doesn't.

Does Mono provide a library for locking other Linux devices, e.g. a custom char device `/dev/custom-char-device` via `/var/lock/LCK..custom-char-device`?

(Note: now I'm not even sure what is the "right way" to lock serial ports in Linux; see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316722/what-is-the-best-practice-for-locking-serial-ports-and-other-devices-in-linux) about that.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944004/c-sharp-serialport-open-does-not-throw-an-exception-if-port-is-already-open-in

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, using `flock()` locking of serial ports or other devices is the way to go in Linux (following Debian's lead in [Debian bug #734086](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734086)).

I found an [advisory locking example in Mono C#](https://gist.github.com/mrvaldes/6196035), however that uses `fcntl()` locking rather than `flock()` locking, and [these two methods are different in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409780/flock-vs-lockf-on-linux).

So I think it would be necessary to use a native helper library to provide `flock()`, which is called via [Interop with Native Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/). The `flock()` function needs to be passed a native file descriptor, which can be obtained from a `FileStream` via `fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()`.